# Best way to detect if an Ember.Object is dirty

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember object and i'd like to know if it is in a dirty state.

```
var App.Post = Ember.Object.create({
   title: "Test",
   isDirty: false
});
App.Post.set("title", "Test2");
App.Post.get("isDirty") // Should === true
```

For the moment, I have tried overloading the set for the object

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.create({
   set: function(path, value) {
       this._super(path, value);
       this._super("isDirty", true);
   }
})
```

It works when I am calling directly myObject.set but it doesn't seem to use that set function when using embers binding. I added logs and this method isn't called by the regular emberjs bindings workflow.

Another thing I've tried is to add an observers to toggle the dirty flag.

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.create({
   hasBeenModified: function() {
      this.set("isDirty", true);
   }.observes("title")
})
```

For a reason still unknown, when I use observes at the model level my bindings do not work anymore in the UI.

Comment: You might want to look into ember-data.  It provides you with a Model object (which is extended from Object) which takes care of all your "isDirty" needs.  It has a bunch of other nice features which makes fetching/updating model object & creating model relationships easy.  And in your higher levels you should not be worrying about the "isDirty" state anymore.  One of the main points of using ember is to stop worrying about all the management of data state and just bind templates to data (your data update and the templates update; no extra bootstrapping needed).

Comment: Since I don't use ember-data at all, I'd rather have something where I don't need to add ember-data only for validating dirtyness. I think I'll just try to deepCopy, deepCompare my object in question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may also need to override setUnknownProperty. The UI is using `Ember.set(object, key, value)`. If you look at the implementation

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/property_set.js#L60
It doesn't call your setter, but will call `setUnknownProperty` if it exists.

Actually, at

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/property_set.js#L52

It looks like they will call your setter if you have predefined the field in your `App.Post` class.